# Check if value exists in Firebase Realtime Database in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a method where i can check if value exists in ReactJS

Her is my structure

```
{
  "users": {
    "VwkBsyDpV8TD2uflpl5fHausaWF2": {
      "email" : "example@gmail.com",
      "username" : "Tom,
    },
    "KgWBsDDpVfia2uflpl5fHausaWF2": {
      "email" : "example@gmail.com",
      "username" : "John,
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the Realtime Database to check if a "value" (i.e. a database node) exists.

For example to check if the node for user with ID `VwkBsyDpV8TD2uflpl5fHausaWF2` exists you have to do as follows (see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get)):

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());

const userIdToCheck = "VwkBsyDpV8TD2uflpl5fHausaWF2";

get(child(dbRef, `users/${userIdToCheck}`)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log("DB node for user VwkBsyDpV8TD2uflpl5fHausaWF2 exists!!");
  } 
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Noah, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: "How can I check if a value exists in Firebase without using an ID? For example, in Express and MongoDB, I can use the following code to check if a phone number exists:

const { phoneNumber } = req.body;
const exist = await User.findOne({ phoneNumber });
if (exist) {
  res.send("This number is already taken.");
  return;
}
How can I accomplish the same thing in Firebase?"